# How to submit a function to the Dask if the function is not in module level?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, dask, dask-distributed

I have scipy sparse matrix in the dask distributed system. I want to convert this to array and leave in the distributed system. I can do that in my local machine like this:

```
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix
coo_matrix((3, 4), dtype=np.int8).toarray()
```

This returns an array. I tried to convert the sparse matrix like below:

```
from scipy import sparse
# Some code here
#
#
my_sparse_matrix = sparse.coo_matrix((3, 4), dtype=np.int8)
my_sparse_matrix = client.scatter(my_sparse_matrix)  # Send to the distributed system
# submit conversion function (to the distributed system)
my_result = self.client.submit(sparse.csr_matrix.toarray, my_sparse_matrix)
client.gather(my_result)
```

which returned this error:

```
{AttributeError}_swap not found
```

And I am getting this error because `.toarray()` is not a module-level function. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine, but I believe you have a typo: you should use the method appropriate to the object you want to act on, but you have used `csr_matrix` in the `submit` call instead of `coo_matrix` which is what `my_sparse_matrix` references. The following works:

```
>>> from scipy import sparse
>>> my_sparse_matrix = sparse.coo_matrix((3, 4), dtype=np.int8)
>>> my_sparse_matrix = client.scatter(my_sparse_matrix)
>>> my_result = client.submit(sparse.coo_matrix.toarray, my_sparse_matrix)
>>> client.gather(my_result)
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int8)
```

It is unfortunate that the error message doesn't give you an obvious cause, but you get the same message without Dask:

```
>>> arr = sparse.coo_matrix((3, 4), dtype=np.int8)
>>> parse.csc_matrix.toarray(arr)
AttributeError: _swap not found
```

Comment: I don't know how I missed that but thank you. I will accept your answer as soon as I try...

Comment: I might have found a foolproof way to do this. Instead of `client.submit(sparse.coo_matrx.toarray, my_sparse_matrix)`, using this: `client.submit(my_sparse_matrix.type.toarray, my_sparse_matrix)` should work for both `csr_matrix` and `coo_matrix` (any maybe some other formats too). Dask futures holds the actual type of data.

Comment: `client.submit(lambda mat: mat.toarray(), sparse matrix)` ?